# I cannot install anything anymore due to unmet dependencies

Tags: 14.04, dependencies, qgis

i tried reinstalling QGIS after not being able to find a plugin in the plugin manager. Now it seems that i cannot install anything anymore. Somehow also my gedit is gone and i can't install it anymore...
when i try to install:

```
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis
```

i get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
qgis is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-qgis : Depends: python-qt4 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python-sip but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python-qgis-common (= 2.0.1-2build2) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python-psycopg2 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python-qscintilla2 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python-pyspatialite but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
               Depends: sip-api-11.0
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried most recommendations in the forums but nothing has worked so far.
unfortunately i am also not experienced with Linux.
I would be very glad about some help!

Comment: If you really tried "most recommendations in the forums", then you probably discovered that you have a *version conflict* that random incantations won't solve. You unwisely added a non-Ubuntu source which provided packages that conflict with your system. That's what the error message about "*you have requested an impossible situation*" means. Uninstall ALL packages from that source to restore your system to proper function. There are many similar questions in AskUbuntu to tell you how.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to run `sudo apt-get -f install`. It should walk down the dependency tree and install any missing or broken packages. If that doesn't work, try to manually install the packages by running the command:`sudo apt-get install python-qt4 python-sip python-qgis-common python-psycopg2  python-qscintilla2 python-pyspatialite python:any  sip-api-11.0`. If that fails, than there is something wrong with the system. As a last resort, I suggest running a release upgrade to 17.04 by running `sudo do-release-upgrade` and fix the problem.